# Bi directional OneToOne does not refresh

Tags: jpa

I am exploring JPA through NetBeans 8.1 with Java DB as database and EclipseLink(JPA 2.1) provider. I am trying OneToOne bidirectional relationship. I have 2 classes Student and Subject.

Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Student() {}
    public Student(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public static void print(EntityManager entitymanager)
    {
            //Print the database
        List<Student>     list=(List<Student>)entitymanager.createQuery("select e from Student e").getResultList( );
        System.out.println("Student");
        System.out.println("Id\tName\tSubject");
        for( Student e:list ) System.out.println(e.getId()+"\t"+e.getName()+"\t"+e.getSubject().getId());
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    Subject subject;
    public Subject getSubject() { return subject; }
    public void setSubject(Subject subject) { this.subject = subject; }
}
```

Subject.java

```
@Entity
public class Subject implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     // Increment of 1
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Subject() {}
    public Subject(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "subject", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Student student;
    public Student getStudent() { return student; }
    public void setStudent(Student student) { this.student = student; }

    public static void print(EntityManager entitymanager)
    {
        //Print the database
        List<Subject> list=(List<Subject>)entitymanager.createQuery("select e from Subject e").getResultList( );
        System.out.println("Subject");
        System.out.println("Id\tName\tStudent");
        for( Subject e:list ) {System.out.println(e.getId()+"\t"+e.getName()+"\t"+(e.student == null ? "null":e.student.getId()));}
    }
}
```

main() function

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Get entity manager and begin the transaction
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA_TestPU");
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
        entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();


        System.out.println("\nREAD : ");
        Student.print(entitymanager); Subject.print(entitymanager);

        Subject maths = new Subject();
        maths.setName("Maths");

        Student archit = new Student();
        archit.setName("Archit");
        archit.setSubject(maths);
        entitymanager.persist(archit);

        entitymanager.flush();

        System.out.println("\nCREATE : Archit selected Maths");

        // I want to print maths.getStudent(), which does not work        
        System.out.println("-----------"+maths.getId()+"---"+maths.getStudent());

        Student.print(entitymanager); Subject.print(entitymanager);

        Subject science = new Subject();
        science.setName("Science");
        archit.setSubject(science);
        entitymanager.persist(archit);

        entitymanager.flush();

        System.out.println("\nUPDATE : Archit selected Science");
        Student.print(entitymanager); Subject.print(entitymanager);

        // Commit and close entity manager
        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();

        entitymanager.close();
        emfactory.close();
    }
```

I expect that Subject.print() should get the good value of member "student", but it is null.

The output of main()

```
READ : 
Student
Id  Name    Subject
Subject
Id  Name    Student

CREATE : Archit selected Maths
-----------1---null
Student
Id  Name    Subject
1   Archit  1
Subject
Id  Name    Student
1   Maths   null

UPDATE : Archit selected Science
Student
Id  Name    Subject
1   Archit  2
Subject
Id  Name    Student
2   Science null
```

I observe that the database is properly updated and Student table has SubjectID but Subject table does not have StudentID.

Can anyone explain me why I am not getting student value in Subject object ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JPA. At no point do you call subject.setStudent(student); so I'm not sure what else you would expect. I am also confused as to why you would expect student FK to be in subject table when Student has a FK to subject.

Comment: Thanks Alan for your comment.
I am not doing subject.setStudent() explictly. But when I run the main() second time, then subject.print() method correctly gets the student value (from database) and prints it's id.
Is my assumption that when I call student.persist() it should update the subject object in memory (because it is bidirectional relation) and persist subject object, wrong?

Comment: I modified Student.setSubjcet() to have statement subject.setStudent(this). This gives me student info from subject object.          I observed a strange behavior that student does not get persisted unless I removed code

           Subject science = new Subject();
            science.setName("Science");
            archit.setSubject(science);
            entitymanager.persist(archit);

Comment: Is my assumption that when I call student.persist() it should update the subject object in memory. **Wrong**. However the relationship will be set when you reload from the DB.

Comment: Thanks Alan for your comment. I also request your opinion on another question with title "Bi directional One To Many relation does not work" 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764374/bi-directional-one-to-many-relation-does-not-work