# Bi directional One To Many relation does not work

Tags: jpa

I am exploring JPA through NetBeans 8.1 with Java DB as database and EclipseLink(JPA 2.1) provider. I am trying OneToMany bidirectional relationship. I have 2 classes Student and Subject.

Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Student() {}
    public Student(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    List<Subject> subject;
    public List<Subject> getSubject() { return subject; }
    public void setSubject(List<Subject> subject) { this.subject = subject; }

    public static void print(EntityManager entitymanager)
    {
        //Print the database
        List<Student> list=(List<Student>)entitymanager.createQuery("select e from Student e").getResultList( );
        System.out.println("Student");
        System.out.println("Id\tName\tSubjectId");
        for( Student e:list ) { System.out.print(e.getId()+"\t"+e.getName()+"\t"); for(Subject s : e.subject) System.out.print(s.getId()+",");System.out.println();}
    }
}
```

Subject.java

```
@Entity
public class Subject implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Subject() {}
    public Subject(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    public Student getStudent() { return student; }
    public void setStudent(Student student) { this.student = student; }

    public static void print(EntityManager entitymanager)
    {
            //Print the database
        List<Subject> list=(List<Subject>)entitymanager.createQuery("select e from Subject e").getResultList( );
        System.out.println("Subject");
        System.out.println("Id\tName\tStudent");
        for( Subject e:list ) System.out.println(e.getId()+"\t"+e.getName()+"\t"+(e.student == null ? "null":e.student.getId()));
    }
}
```

main() function

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Get entity manager and begin the transaction
    EntityManagerFactory emfactory = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA_TestPU");
    EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
    entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();

    System.out.println("\nREAD : ");
    Student.print(entitymanager); Subject.print(entitymanager);

    LinkedList<Subject> pcm = new LinkedList<Subject>();
    Subject maths = new Subject();
    maths.setName("Maths");
    entitymanager.persist(maths);
    pcm.add(maths);
    Subject science = new Subject();
    science.setName("Science");
    entitymanager.persist(science);
    pcm.add(science);

    Student archit = new Student();
    archit.setName("Archit");
    archit.setSubject(pcm);
    entitymanager.flush();
    entitymanager.persist(archit);
    entitymanager.flush();

    System.out.println("\nCREATE : Archit selected Maths Science");
    Student.print(entitymanager); Subject.print(entitymanager);

    // Commit and close entity manager
    entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();

    entitymanager.close();
    emfactory.close();
}
```

First execution of main()

```
READ :
Student
Id  Name    SubjectId
Subject
Id  Name    Student

CREATE : Archit selected Maths Science
Student
Id  Name    SubjectId
1   Archit  2,1,
Subject
Id  Name    Student
1   Science null
2   Maths   null
```

Second execution of main()

```
READ :
Student
Id  Name    SubjectId
1   Archit
Subject
Id  Name    Student
1   Science null
2   Maths   null

CREATE : Archit selected Maths Science
Student
Id  Name    SubjectId
1   Archit
2   Archit  3,4,
Subject
Id  Name    Student
1   Science null
2   Maths   null
3   Maths   null
4   Science null
```

I see that when Student is saved, subjects are also saved. The SUBJECT table contains column STUDENT_ID as FK. But this column is set to NULL instead of value of Id of Student object. At the same time in memory object of Subject does not contain valid reference of Student object, but it is set as NULL.

Can anyone help me identifying if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, you never initialized SubjectOTM.studentOTM. So it's null. As simple as that. BTW, your naming (and layout) makes your code very hard to read. Just use Student and Subject. And rename the field subjectOTM to subjects, with an `s`, since it's a list of subjects, containing several subjects.

Comment: Thanks Nizet for your review. I have changed the naming convention.

I wrote my code refering to site http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm.

I tried initiating Subject.student in constructor Subject(), but it give IllegalStateException. Can you please explain how the initialization can be done ?

Comment: `science.setStudent(archit); maths.setStudent(archit);`.

Comment: Thanks Nizet. It worked.

I have a doubt. Is my expectaion that entitymanager.persist(archit), while saving Student and then subjects, should also set relation between Subject -> Student, incorrect ?

This relations gets autmatically set in One to One bidirectional mapping when entitymanager.persist(archit) is called.